# Finding Sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to find the sample space to following experiment.
You throw a cube and every time you score at least a 4, you flip a coin. 
How can I write that down. I have single elements and pairs?

My idea: $$\Omega =\{ 1,2,3, 4T, 4H,....,6H\}$$

Can I write that in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

A sample space looks something like [this](http://www.mathwords.com/s/sample_space.htm?ref=s0d.org) ([here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/) is how to make a table using MathJax).

You have possibilities for the die on one axis, and possibilities for the coin on the other axis. This will give you $4,5,6$ on the top, and $H, T$ on the left.

Then note that fact that you have to roll the dice first, so something like $H4$ is not possible.

Comment: Is  $$\Omega =\{ 1,2,3, 4T, 4H,....,6H\}$$ that right?

Comment: First of all, you can exclude $\{1,2,3\}$, since you cannot flip the coin after that, so it is not a valid outcome. You also need to arrange the information in a table.

Comment: I dont understand how I can write that down?

Comment: Using [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/) page.

Comment: But why do I need such a table?

Comment: The information is presented more clearly with a table. Try using your method with a hundred possibilities on one event, and a hundred possibilities for the other event. It will be hard to see which outcomes are impossible, or what all the possibilities are since some of them will be at the very end of the list.

Comment: Ok I see. But my possible solution is not wrong?

Comment: You can write it like that, but I feel you are making things harder for yourself if you don't use a table.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. Thank you.  I will create the table on paper:)